# MQTT instead of wss on browser

Tags: reactjs, websocket, mqtt, iot

When I run this code with nodejs, it works fine both on wss(code commented) and mqtts protocol. However if I run this on browser, it only works with wss. I tried bundling with browserify; I tried using cdn but no luck with mqtt protocol. I want to use mqtt protocol because data is not realtime in wss protocol.

```
const mqtt = require('mqtt');
const client = mqtt.connect("mqtts://mqtt.some.com", {
    username: "some",
    password: "somepassword",
    port: 8883,
});

// const client = mqtt.connect("wss://mqtt.some.com", {
//   username: "some",
//   password: "somepassword",
//   port: 8083,
// });

client.on('connect', () => {
    console.log('connected');
    client.subscribe('body_data/1/91', { qos: 1 })
});

client.on('message', function (topic, message, packet) {
    console.log("=====================================================================");
    console.log(message.toString(), new Date(Date.now()).toUTCString());
});
```

Here's the error I get when running mqtt protocol on browser
[image: mqtt error]

Answer (score 1):

You can **ONLY** use WebSocket based connections from the browser.

The browser's JavaScript sandbox will only allow HTTP based protocols (WebSockets bootstrap over HTTP) so it will always fail if you try to use a native TCP socket.

There should be absolutely no difference in message delivery when connecting via MQTT over WebSockets Vs native MQTT

Comment: Message delivery has significant difference over MQTT and WebSocket. I can show you the difference recorded in MQTT explorer. The problem we are facing is, WS delays transmission.

Comment: Then you need to look at your MQTT broker as it is broken. You still can not use anything other than MQTT over WebSockets from the browser