# Pyscript MQTT publishing message

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio, mqtt, pyscript

I'm working on py-script html page and I want to publish a message via mqtt in a specific topic.
I put the python code in the tag

```
import asyncio
import os
import signal
import time
    
from gmqtt import Client as MQTTClient
    
STOP = asyncio.Event()
   
    
def on_connect(client, flags, rc, properties):
        print('Connected')
        client.subscribe('TEST/#', qos=0)
    
    
def on_message(client, topic, payload, qos, properties):
        print(payload)
    
    
def on_disconnect(client, packet, exc=None):
        print('Disconnected')
    
def on_subscribe(client, mid, qos, properties):
        print('SUBSCRIBED')
    
 
    
async def main(broker_host):
        client = MQTTClient("3232DZQ")
    
        client.on_connect = on_connect
        client.on_message = on_message
        client.on_disconnect = on_disconnect
        client.on_subscribe = on_subscribe
     
        await client.connect(broker_host)
    
        client.publish('TEST/TIME', 'IZISIUIQY', qos=1)

        await STOP.wait()
        await client.disconnect()

def ask_exit(*args):
    STOP.set()    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop() 
        host = 'broker.hivemq.com' 
        loop.run_until_complete(main(host))
```

When I run the python file alone it works fine:
[python file working fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Oj9Q.png)
, but when I put the code in the tags, I doesn't work. The html page that I want to run and publish message via mqtt, points on the python file using the tag pyscript and the attribute src="publish.py"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head> 

    <title>Publish MQTT</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css" /> 
<script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>
    <py-env>
        - gmqtt
    </py-env> 
  </head>

  <body>

  <!--calling publish python code-->
<py-script src="publish.py"></py-script>

  </body>
</html>
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvuBd.png)

Comment: Please can anyone run this code in his machine to discover the issue

Comment: To connect from within a browser you will need to use [MQTT over Websockets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71969247/11810946); unfortunately [it appears that `gmqtt` does not yet support this fully](https://github.com/wialon/gmqtt/issues/67).

Comment: I see the answer that you posted and deleted. In my answer, you have multiple problems. All problems must be solved and not just one item. One item requires modifying gmqtt as it is not compatible with the APIs available in the browser.

Comment: Note that there is an [experimental branch in the gmqtt repo](https://github.com/wialon/gmqtt/tree/support-ws-transport) with websocket support (and there are other MQTT libraries with websocket support). However having Python code that works using websockets provides no guarantee that pyscript will be able to convert it to something that will work in the browser (pyscript uses  pyodide so [this issue](https://github.com/pyodide/pyodide/issues/574) is probably relevant).

Answer (score 0):

The package **gmqtt** requires the operating system TCP Sockets API.

The Sockets API is not available in web browsers. This is a security restriction for all browser-based applications. The only solution is to modify the **gmqtt** package to use the Fetch API.

Your code uses the `__main__` convention which does not exist in PyScript. Just remove that line.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

The next small item is that you do not need to create an event loop. Remove this line:

```
loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
```

You can just use this code:

```
await loop.run_until_complete(main(host))
```

I wrote an article on how to catch the errors that your program reported:

[PyScript: Debugging and Error Management Strategies](https://www.jhanley.com/pyscript-debugging-and-error-management-strategies/)